# How to set select box height in jquery moblie?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to set select box height same to label (模板分類:).

1. `<select id="TamplateClass" style="height:1.5em">...</select>`
2. use CSS `#TamplateClass{height:1.5em;}`

But results are all the same, see this image:

[image: select element with Chinese label]

#### HTML:

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
        <label>模板分類：</label>
        <select id="TamplateClass" >
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I do?

Comment: If you want a smaller version of the selectmenu, add `data-mini="true"` to the `select` tag, like this: `<select id="TamplateClass" data-mini="true">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile creates a DIV with an ID of the selectid + "-button".  You could override the top and bottom padding of this div to get the height you want:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
    <label>模板分類：</label>
    <select id="TamplateClass" >
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>

#TamplateClass-button {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/twctfyp1/)**